# iPhone Splash Page Specs Required by Apple

Tags: iphone

What are the specifications required by Apple for a splash page for a custom iPhone application?

Answer (score 5):

The official UI guide states that the splash should match the first screen the customer sees, sans the dynamically generated/loaded data. However, the App Store is full of apps that violate this requirement and provide splash screens with branding, art and whatnot.

Comment: The idea is that your splash is meant give the user the illusion of an instant-launch, making it look like the app has already loaded its UI as soon as you touch the icon. Obviously, the reality is a bit further from the truth, and as Seva says, Apple doesn't seem interested in enforcing this guideline in the App store.

Answer (score 1):

You can check Apple Developer [Iphone Human Interface Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconsImages/IconsImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH14-SW5) there is a full explanation over there, quick and dirty your launch image should:

- Measures 320 x 480 pixels. Including
  the status bar area allows you to
  display the status bar color you’ve
  chosen immediately, instead of
  displaying it after your application
  has finished starting.
- Is identical to the first screen of
  the application, except for: Text.
  The launch image is static, so any
  text you display in it will not be
  localized. User interface elements
  that might change. Avoid including
  elements that might look different
  when the application finishes
  launching, so that users don’t
  experience a flash between the launch
  image and the first application
  screen.

The easiest way of doing this is taking a screenshot of some image on the screen of your iphone.

Comment: Um, depending on functionality. If the content of the first view is, say, loaded from some kind of a Web/Net service, then a screenshot won't do. Should be a screenshot with blanks where the downloaded stuff is.

Again, that's according to the guideline.